# Match the 4th number in a string using a regular expression

Tags: regex

I need to match the 4th number in a string of 6 numbers using a regular expression.

1. *These numbers use comma (,) as a thousands separator and a full stop (.) as a decimal separator.*
2. *Numbers will always contain a full stop but not always a comma.*
3. *Each number is separated by a space*

**Example:** String of numbers separated by spaces:

> 35,362.843 1,261.94 0.000 35,362.843 1,257.43 44,466,154.16

My regular expression using look ahead and look behind

```
(?<= )(\d*,*\d*\.\d*)(?= \d*,*\d*\.)
```

**Actual outcome**

> 1,261.94 0.000 35,362.843

**Expected outcome**

> 35,362.843

Comment: Please precise the tool and regex flavour you're using.

Comment: Out of curiosity- why do you need a regex here?

Comment: In your example, you get the 3rd number, do you want the 3rd or the 4th? A solution should be to split on space then get the 3rd (the 4th) element of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
^(?:[\d,.]+\s){3}([\d.,]+)
```

and use the first capture group, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rJS19k/1/).

---

The expression reads as

```
^                 # start of string / line
(?:[\d,.]+\s){3}  # non-capturing group with a character class [0-9,.] 
                  # followed by a whitespace, thrice
([\d.,]+)         # the part in question -> group 1
```

---

But even better yet: split on whitespaces programmatically and use the resulting `array[3]` (when starting to count from zero that is).

Answer (score 0):

The capture group named "fourth" (capture group 1) will give you the expected result:

```
(?<number>\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d*){0}(?:(?&number) ){3}(?<fourth>(?&number))(?=(?: (?&number)){2})
```

---

Lets break it apart:

```
(?<number>\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d*){0}
```

defines the name "number", where a number is defined as

1. having at least one and at most 3 digits
2. optianally followed by an infinite amount of komma and three digits
3. a necessary period
4. an infinite amount of digits (or none)

---

```
(?:(?&number) ){3}
```

Match three numbers all followed by a single space. Lookbehinds are not supported, because a number does not have a fixed length.

---

```
(?<fourth>(?&number))
```

Match a single number, no space included.

---

```
(?=(?: (?&number)){2})
```

Assert that there are two more space separated numbers.

---

#### As simple regex

if your regex engine does not allow named capturing groups, then this simple regex will do the same job:

```
 (?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d* ){3}(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d*)(?=(?: \d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d*){2})
```